# Earth Engine - returning/passing values between UI widgets

Tags: google-earth-engine

Runnable code snippet here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/24f4e6e5b961e18c7200fd58884fff17

I am building an app that will display a geometry and some data on the map based on user input from multiple `ui.Select` dropdown menus. My goal is to have the user choose her parameters from each dropdown, then click a button labeled Submit to add the geometry/data to the map all at once. Currently I can add the geometry to the map as part of the `onChange` function, but I am having issues returning a value from that function to pass to another widget. Here is a code snippet:

```
var map = ui.Map();
var states = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States').toList(60);

function makeDropdown() {
  var dropdownItems = states.map(function(el){
    return ee.Feature(el).get('NAME');
  }).sort();
  var placeholder = 'Select a state...';

  // Dropdown menu
  var select = ui.Select({
    items: dropdownItems.getInfo(),
    onChange: function(key) {
      var newGeo = states.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', key));
      var newGeoLayer = ee.Feature(newGeo.get(0)).geometry();
      // Uncomment to add state to map - this works.
      // map.addLayer(newGeoLayer, null, 'Selected state');
      // map.centerObject(newGeoLayer, 6);
    }
  });

  // Submit button - this doesn't work.
  var submit = ui.Button({
    label: 'Submit',
    onClick: function(newGeoLayer) {
      map.addLayer(newGeoLayer, null, 'Selected region');
      map.centerObject(newGeoLayer, 6);
    }
  });

  select.setPlaceholder(placeholder);
  return ui.Panel([select, submit], ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'));
}

// Initialize the split panel UI.
function init() {
  var panel = ui.Panel({
    style: {width: '30%', border: '3px solid #ddd'}
  });
  var dropdownPanel = ui.Panel();
  panel.add(dropdownPanel);
  var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
    firstPanel: panel,
    secondPanel: map,
  });

  ui.root.clear();
  ui.root.add(splitPanel);
  dropdownPanel.add(makeDropdown());
  return dropdownPanel;
}

var panels = init();
```

What I am hoping to accomplish in this example is to define `newGeoLayer` inside the `onChange` function of the `ui.Select` widget, but also return it somehow so I can pass it to the `ui.Button` widget. Right now the `newGeoLayer` variable is only defined inside the function and is out of scope for the button widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare the variable in the scope where you want it to be available (the entire `makeDropdown`), separately from assigning to it:

```
function makeDropdown() {
  var newGeoLayer;      // NEW

  ...

  // Dropdown menu
  var select = ui.Select({
    items: dropdownItems.getInfo(),
    onChange: function(key) {
      var newGeo = states.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', key));
      newGeoLayer = ee.Feature(newGeo.get(0)).geometry();      // NO "var" HERE
    }
  });

  ...
}
```

I've marked the two changes. I added `var newGeoLayer` at the top of the function, to declare the variable in the proper scope, and removed `var` inside the `onChange` function so that it is an **assignment to the existing variable** rather than a new variable.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I had a feeling I was close but couldn't put the whole thing together.